# Writing matrix version of an equation using vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

My Equations:

$y_1 = 3x_1 + 5x_2$

$y_2 = x_1 + 2x_2$

How can I write the matrix versions of the equations above using vectors
$y = (y_1,y_2)^T$ and $x = (x_1,x_2)^T$

Comment: Why don't you start with $y=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}x$, and try to figure out $a,b,c,d$?

Comment: What does the tag `differential-equations` have to do with the question?